# Xunit The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data

Tags: .net, xunit

I keep getting this error while using XUnit for .NET 1.0 framework net46.

> The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data

I have seen this post: [Collection fixture won't inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319903/collection-fixture-wont-inject) and followed the instructions regarding collection fixture closely as described here:

http://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html#collection-fixture

Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions to what might cause this?

Answer (score 21):

In my case it turned out to be a matter of doing it right according to the instructions. By mistake I had annotated the class with

```
 [Collection("ProjectCollection")]
```

instead of:

```
 [Collection("ActorProjectCollection")]
```

I must say that the dependency injection mechanism of XUnit would be greatly improved if the error messages gave more explicit hint of what is wrong.

Comment: May help guard against these spelling mistakes by using `nameof(ActorProjectCollection)`

Answer (score 14):

Another scenario in which this might fail is if the `[CollectionDefinition]` is defined on a type outside the executing test assembly. The attribute itself needs to be defined inside of it or xUnit won't pick it up.

Comment: This happened to me. The class defined by `CollectionDefinition` and `Collection` have different namespaces.

Answer (score 6):

This exception may arise when the constructor of your fixture class is failing due to some other problem, in my case connecting to a local Mongo server.

Either look for other failures and solve those first or lighten your constructor up so it does less.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had to implement the IClassFixture<> interface on the test class.

```
public class MyTests : IClassFixture<QueryTestFixture>
```

After I moved the QueryTestFixture to another project the Class attribute stopped working

```
[Collection("QueryCollection")]
```

Which was linked to the implementation in the fixture class (see below)

```
[CollectionDefinition("QueryCollection")]
public class QueryCollection : ICollectionFixture<QueryTestFixture> { }
```

I had tried many alternative ways to solve this but ended up [reading the xunit.net explanation about shared context.](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context) which provided a solution.

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me a couple of times just after adding the `Collection` and the `CollectionDefinition` decorators and I always arrive to this answer when looking on Internet.

But in my case the problem was just that it seems that a **'Clean Solution'** action is needed before testing whether it works or not. Without cleaning the solution I always get a `The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data` error.

So, I write also this answer in order to help my future self.

---

Anyway, in order to avoid the problem explained by [Nikola Schou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445414/684128), you can always use a constant to avoid name mistmatching:

```
public static class Collections
{
    public const string ActorProjectCollection= "ActorProjectCollection";
}
```

-

```
[Collection(Collections.ActorProjectCollection)]
/// ...
```

-

```
[CollectionDefinition(Collections.ActorProjectCollection)]
/// ...
```

Comment: I had the same issue. I couldn't execute multiple tests at once after refactoring my fixtures (they worked if i ran them one by one). After a clean up in VS it worked fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that there should only be one class decorated with CollectionDefinition per collection key.

Answer (score 1):

definition in the same namespace

```
  [CollectionDefinition("Integration Tests", DisableParallelization = true)]
    public class TestCollection : ICollectionFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
        // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
        // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.
    }
```

usage in the same namespace

```
    [Collection("Integration Tests")]
    public class BasicControllerTests
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

        public BasicControllerTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

 ...
```

[source](https://medium.com/imaginelearning/asp-net-core-3-1-microservice-quick-start-c0c2f4d6c7fa)

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:
looking at the posted responses I checked the following:

- CollectionDefinition(X) and Collection(X) classes are in the same assembly
- Both the definition and the classes using it refer to the same collection name
- The classes using the definition have a constructor receiving the fixture

But still not working... What was the problem? The class with the definition has not the `public` modifier (`class Definition ...`) while the classes using the definition have it.

Just added the `public` to the definition, and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

in my case i wasnt make FixtureClass public

```
   [CollectionDefinition(nameof(ApiTestCollection))]
    **public** class ApiTestCollection : ICollectionFixture<OpenSchoolApiBroker>
    {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had my `Fixture` inside of the `CollectionDefinition` instead of the `FixtureCollection`.

For example:

**Fixture Code**

```
public class MyFixture { ... }
```

**Not Working**

```
[CollectionDefinition(nameof(MyFixture))]
public class MyFixtureCollection : ICollection<MyFixture> {}
```

**Working**

```
[CollectionDefinition(nameof(MyFixtureCollection))]
public class MyFixtureCollection : ICollection<MyFixture> {}
```